# how to treat touches separately

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a little game and I have come across a problem that I haven't been able to solve. The thing is that when I touch the screen an action occours. Well, I want that if there are 2 differents touches the action to happen 2 times, not only on the first one. Right now, if there are 2 players on the same device, the one who touches first is the one who wins, because the second player isn't able to even call the action. How can I invoke the action two times treating every touch recived as input?

In other words, I want to detect when there are two fingers on the screen and *split* every "finger" in the normal action for one finger.

Of course, my actions takes place here:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //code to get input info
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
 //calling actions with the arguments of touchesEnded and with the ones of touchesBegan
}
```

Comment: I guess that you will split the screen somehow, say one half of the screen is for the player 1 and the other is for player 2 ? If so, just detect to position of the touch and see who is won based on touch location.

Comment: well tried but wrong guess… thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

In your storyboard, you need to enable "Multiple Touch" for your view (it's in the Interaction section of the Attributes Inspector.)  You can also set this property programmatically:

```
view.multipleTouchEnabled = true
```

However, if multiple touches happen at the same time, they will be passed in a single `touchesBegan` event.  To make sure your app detects both touches, iterate over all of the touches in the set in `touchesBegan`:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        //code to get input info
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this should work. Tomorrow I will try it!